# Removing items with specific names from ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I've got an ArrayList that can sometimes contain the values "Time (GMT)", "None", and "No Sensor" at various positions. I want to remove all instances of those, so I wrote this little for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < trackedFieldsMod.size(); i++ ) {
    if(trackedFieldsMod.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("Time (GMT)") || trackedFieldsMod.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("None") || trackedFieldsMod.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("No Sensor")) {
        trackedFieldsMod.remove(i); //Don't let users find average/mean/etc for irrelevant fields
    }
}
```

For some reason this will remove the "Time (GMT)" at the beginning of the list, and any "None" or "No Sensor" at the end of the list, but if my ArrayList has a "None" or "No Sensor" in the middle anywhere, they are not removed. I can't for the life of me figure out why. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you remove a list item at position i the item that used to be at i + 1 will be moved to i (everything moves 1 cell towards i).

However, in your next for loop iteration i becomes i + 1 so basically you are skipping that item which previously moved from i + 1 to i on your remove operation. You need to decrement i when you are removing an item.

Comment: That only applies if there are two adjacent occurrences, though.

Comment: But of course. My friend, you are a gentleman, and a scholar. I'll accept your answer in about 7 minutes haha

Comment: Using Iterator and [Iterator.remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) on match is probably simplest.

Comment: I played with iterators, but I've only ever used them in C++, and with Java's lack of pointers I was just left confused and upset. But yeah, I understand that iterators solve this problem

Answer (score 4):

I'd generally use an iterator to do this:

```
for (Iterator<String> iterator = trackedFieldsMod.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String string = iterator.next();
     if("Time (GMT)".equalsIgnoreCase(string) || "None".equalsIgnoreCase(string) || "No Sendor".equalsIgnoreCase(string)) {
            iterator.remove(); //Don't let users find average/mean/etc for irrelevant fields
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness I'll add that you can also use some convenience methods to do this sort of thing:

```
List<String> toRemove = Arrays.asList("Time (GMT)", "None", "No Sendor");
trackedFieldsMod.removeAll( toRemove );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use contains method of string.. it should solve your problem